# Answer does not make sense using conditional probability

Tags: probability

As of now, there are 64.1 million people residing in the UK. 5.4 million of them are thought to be asthmatic. A new test for asthma has recently been introduced and medical trials indicate that

- in patients with asthma, the test correctly returns positive 68% of the time
- in patients that does not suffer from asthma, the test correctly returns 82% of the time.

Assuming a patient undergo medical inspection. What is the probability that the patient has asthma,

1. if the test comes back positive?
2. if the test comes back negative?

For **Part 1**, I used this method:

Step 1:
$$
P(A|+)=\frac{P(+|A)P(A)}{P(+)}
$$

Step 2:
$$
P(+)=P(+│A)P(A)+P(+│N)P(N)=(0.68)\left(\frac{54}{641}\right)+(0.18)\left(\frac{587}{641}\right)=\frac{7119}{32050}
$$

Step 3:
$$
P(A│+)=\frac{P(+|A)P(A)}{P(+)}=\frac{0.68\times\frac{54}{641}}{\frac{7119}{32050}}=\frac{204}{791}=25.79\%
$$

For **Part 2**, I used the same method as Part 1 but I got a very small answer. Assuming if I insert all the values in the equations correctly, would it be sensible if my answer for **Part 2** is 3.47%?

However, personally, it does not make logical sense if the probability of test returning negative is 3.47% because that would mean almost everyone in the nation would be asthmatic.

Or I could just write it as 
$$
100-25.79 = 74.21%
$$
but I'm afraid this isn't the answer given the complexity of the question.

Comment: 3.47% is the right answer here...

Comment: You're computing the probability of a false negative not the probability someone doesn't have asthma. False negatives are rare and should be rare intuitively. Otherwise, the test would be a piece of crap. So, you're right.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. If 3.47% is the correct answer, this is quite reasonable. It says: "If the test says you don't have asthma, then it's very likely you really don't have asthma (i.e. the test is good)." The first answer is actually more surprising. It says: "If the test says you have asthma, it's only 25% likely you actually have it!"  But that isn't that surprising given the low figure of 68% in the hypotheses.

Comment: Would it be realistic to write 100-25.79=74.21%? If not, what's the difference? @ClementC.

Comment: @iterence:  that would not give the probability $\Pr[A\mid -]$, but instead the quantity $\Pr[A^c\mid +] = 1 - \Pr[A\mid +] $. That is, instead of "the probability to have asthma knowing the test says you don't," you would compute "the probability not to have asthma, knowing the test says you do."

Comment: @Frank Now that I slowly think about it, the answer seems to fit in. I was doubtful until I looked at the question again and saw the population statistics

Comment: Cheers for the clear explanation @ClementC.

Comment: In part 2, "if the test comes back negative", it is assumed we _know_ that the result was negative, i.e., the probability of the test returning negative is $100$%, _not_ $3.47$%. The $3.47$% figure arises from the cases where people _do_ have asthma but it is not detected by the test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One instructive way to do these kinds of $2 \times 2$ problems, since there are only four distinct populations, is to enumerate them and calculate the marginal probabilities by inspection.

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|} \hline
& \text{asthmatic} & \text{not asthmatic} & \text{TOTALS} \\ \hline
\text{positive} & 3.672 & 10.566 & 14.238 \\ \hline
\text{negative} & 1.728 & 48.134 & 49.862 \\ \hline
\text{TOTALS} & 5.400 & 58.700 & 64.100 \\ \hline
\end{array}
$$

From this, one can read off

$$
P(\text{asthmatic} \mid \text{positive}) = 3.672/14.238 \doteq 0.25790
$$

and

$$
P(\text{asthmatic} \mid \text{negative}) = 1.728/49.862 \doteq 0.34656
$$

ETA: Two of the cells—$3.672 = (0.68)(5.400)$ and $48.134 = (0.82)(58.7)$—are filled directly by the given parameters.  Everything else is bookkeeping.

The abysmal false positive rate is due to a combination of the low specificity of the test ($82$ percent) and the relatively low prevalence of asthma ($5.4/64.1 \doteq 8.4$ percent), so that although only a minority (sizable, but still a minority) of non-asthmatics test positive, they still dwarf the asthmatics who test positive, because there are so few asthmatics available to test positive in the first place.  Even if the test were $100$ percent sensitive, the false positive rate would still have been $10.566/(10.566+5.400) \doteq 66$ percent.